# How to push logs to fluentd deamonset using logrus

Tags: docker, go, elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd

I have a simple golang application running inside kubernetes which just logs whatever text we place in request params. Code :

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

var (
    logger = logrus.New()
)

func main() {
    //logFile, err := os.OpenFile("/var/log/app.log", os.O_CREATE | os.O_WRONLY | os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    //if err != nil {
    //  panic(err)
    //}
    logger.Out = os.Stdout
    http.HandleFunc("/get", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        content := r.URL.Query().Get("m")
        if content == "" {
            logger.Warn("m is empty")
            content = "nothing"
        }
        logger.Info("content is - ", content)
        w.Write([]byte(content))
    })
    logger.Info("starting server")
    http.ListenAndServe(":9999", nil)
}
```

I have fluentd deamonset running on my local which is connected to elasticsearch (also running in local but not in kubernetes). Now I want my logs to go to elasticsearch and ultimately appear in kibana but that's not happening and I am not able to debug.

My fluentd yaml looks like -

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logging
    version: v1
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: fluentd-logging
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: fluentd-logging
        version: v1
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    spec:
      serviceAccount: fluentd
      serviceAccountName: fluentd
      tolerations:
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
        - name: fluentd
          image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:elasticsearch
          env:
            - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
              value: "minikube-host"
            - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
              value: "9200"
            - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME
              value: "http"
            - name: FLUENT_UID
              value: "0"
            # X-Pack Authentication
            # =====================
            - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER
              value: "elastic"
            - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
              value: "MyPw123"
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 200Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 200Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: varlog
              mountPath: /var/log
            - name: varlibdockercontainers
              mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
              readOnly: true
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
        - name: varlog
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/docker/containers
```

Here `minikube-host` is just a proxy service that fluentd uses to connect to host machine (elasticsearch runs directly on host).

fluentd rbac looks like -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logging
    version: v1

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: kube-system
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - pods
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch

---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: fluentd
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: fluentd
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: fluentd
    namespace: kube-system
```

fluentd is able to push logs to ES because I can see logs from fluentd pod in kibana. Actually I am able to see logs from fluentd pod only (no app logs, no logs from pods running in kube-system)

Not sure if it is relevant: my application runs inside docker with dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.15 as base_image

WORKDIR /go/src/demo

ADD . .

RUN go get -d ./...

RUN go build -o /build/main-linux main.go

WORKDIR /build

CMD ["./main-linux"]
```

and my application deployment file is -

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: demo-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: demo
          image: yashschandra/demo
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9999
      volumes:
        - name: varlog
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log
```

My question is -

What am I missing in my golang application because of which fluentd is not receiving logs from app (ie. why don't I see "starting server" in my kibana)?

I have tried both logging to stdout as well as logging to a file but none is working.

I feel it has something to do with pipelining logs correctly to fluentd but almost all articles I read on the topic does not do anything special

references -

https://www.metricfire.com/blog/logging-for-kubernetes-fluentd-and-elasticsearch/

https://medium.com/kubernetes-tutorials/cluster-level-logging-in-kubernetes-with-fluentd-e59aa2b6093a

Comment: Could you please check logs from your fluentd pod to see if it actually processes kube related logs? This can be done by running `kubectl logs fluentd`. Please add it to the question.